# What happens when you pass a memory address to a function with a pass by pointer arguement?

Tags: c++

I was studying C++ and got confused in this part the following question below:

***What    is  the output  of  the following   program?***

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void displayArray(const int A[], const int no){
   for (int i = 0; i < no; i++)
       cout << A[i] << "\t";
cout << endl;
}

void modifyArray(int *arr, int index){
    arr[index] = arr[0] + 10;
}

int main(){
   int B[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
   displayArray(B,8);
   displayArray(B+3,4);
   modifyArray(B,2);
   modifyArray(B+5,1);
   modifyArray(&(B[3]),4);
   displayArray(B,8);
   return 0;
}
```

I was able to get them correct, except for the one with `modifyArray(&(B[3]),4);`.

What happens when we try to pass the "address" of the `B[3]` to `void modifyArray(int *arr, int index)`?

As a result, I saw that the value at `B[3]` has not changed, but instead, `B[7]` changed. Why?

Comment: How did you determine that "the value at the given index has not changed"?

Comment: Why did you expect `B[3]` to be changed, when this function does not change the value of `arr[0]` (which is what `B[3]` would be, in this function call), but `arr[index]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indexing an array is essentially adding then dereferencing. So, `arr[i] == *(arr + i)`. Thus, `&b[3] == &(*(b + 3))` which is just `b + 3`. Since arrays are contiguous chunks of memory, this is just an array that starts 3 elements over, or `{4, 5, 6, 7, 8}`. So, index 4 of **that** array, which is index 7 of the original array, is set to index 0 of **that** array plus 10. So, b would be `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 14}` (if you get rid of the other `modifyArray` statements).